# How to append link in current URL in Selenium using java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to know how to append link in current URL. For eg: me link is https://www.google.co.in/ in current program now I have to append /#q=ask+questions in this URL.
Please help.
I know how to get current url(by using getCurrentUrl() syntax)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use [URIBuilder](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/URIBuilder). Something like this:

```
String someUrl = "https://www.google.co.in";
// or perhaps
// String someUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl();

URIBuilder uri = new URIBuilder(someUrl);
uri.setPath("search");
uri.addQueryParam("q", "ask+questions");

Assert.assertEquals(uri.toString(), "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ask%2Bquestions");
// or perhaps
// browser.get(uri.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

`getCurrentUrlUrl()` has a return type of String. So you can save it's value and play around like you can with any String.

Take an example, I want to get this url and then append your string and then get() this new webpage:

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
String newurl = url+"/#q=ask+questions";
driver.get(newurl);
```